# Reposition divs depending on web page size, want content to stack vertically when web page shrinks

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am building a personal website in html, with a thin left column, and a main content right column. When the web page shrinks, I want the thin left column to go above the main content. I cannot figure out how to do this, any help?

Here is what I have so far:
First I show my index.html file, then my .css file I use for styling. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>My Name</title>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="res"><a class="res_a">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="res"><a class="res_a">Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</head>

<hr width = 95%>
  <body>

    <div class="wrapper">

      <div class="left">

        <h3 class="name" >My Name</h3>
        <p class = "job">
        Blah blah blah.... 
        </p>

      </div>

      <div class="right">

        <h1 class="about" >About</h1>
        <p class = "bio">
          Main content blah blah blah... 
        </p>

    </div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

.css file:

```
html, body {
  display:  inline-block;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: left;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Castoro', serif;
}

.name {
  font-family: 'Castoro', serif;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 80%;
}

.left {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 15px;
  max-width: 22%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: left;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  /* flex: 50%; */
}

.job {
font-size: 14px
}

.right {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  max-width: 78%;
  flex: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.menu a{
  display: block;
  /* color: white; */
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li a
{
    position: relative;
}

.menu li a:not(.active):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li a:not(.active):hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Comment: I think you are really misunerstanding what the `head` and `body` tags of your page mean. The `head` is *just* for metadata, and the `body` has everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Head is different from header.

Change it fast.

Now  one quick way of making the layout you ask about, its to know how to do a media query.

Use the wrapper with flex-direction: column for the mobile layout,
And inside the query you can use a different dirección.

```
@media (min-width: 700px) {
Flex-direction: row;
// and any others changes you need 
}
```

Its like working in 2 different layouts at the beginning. But with practice you make more and more efficient code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not very difficult to solve, but you seem to have some very basic misunderstandings about how an HTML page should be formed.

It should always be like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    metadata
  </head>
  <body>
    content
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that `<head>` does not represent a header on the page - for that, you could use the `<header>` element, within your `<body>` of course.

Also, an `<hr>` element represents a thematic break on the page, so it doesn't make sense to have one at the very beginning.

Okay, now I'll answer your question: Use a media query to change the `flex-flow` of the wrapper to `row` at screen sizes larger than 600px.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 80%;
}
.wrapper > * {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper {
    flex-flow: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Resize the window to see the layout change...</h1>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <h3 class="name">My Name</h3>
    <p class="job">
      Blah blah blah....
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h3 class="about">About</h3>
    <p class="bio">
      Main content blah blah blah...
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```